# Enabling log in MySQL 5.6 prevents server from starting

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, mysql-5.6

I've installed MySQL 5.6.15 on Mac OSX via Homebrew.

I've added the following lines to `my.cnf` to enable query logging, but the MySQL server is unable to restart with the new lines. How can we solve the problem?

**Added to my.cnf**

```
general_log=1
log=/var/log/mysql-query.log
```

**Error:**

```
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/me-MacBook-Air.local.pid).
```

**Entire my.cnf**

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]

general_log=1
log=/var/log/mysql-query.log

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....
# socket = .....

# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `log` option is [deprecated since 5.6.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log), and you're using 5.6.15.

Use [`general_log_file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log_file) instead:

```
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql-query.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are missing from the path to log file (May be helpful for noobs)

and the exact configuration in my.cnf is:

```
# General Query Log
general_log=1
general_log_file="/var/log/mysql-query.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is bug in MySQL 5.6 version.
Even mysqld show as :

```
    Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
C:\Windows\my.ini C:\Windows\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.cnf
```

Realy settings are reading in following order :

```
    Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini C:\Windows\my.ini C:\Windows\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini c:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.cnf
```

Check file: "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini"

Hope it help somebody.